# Convert general SQL time format in c# ( all variations )?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

If I have theses general *sql valid dates* in c# *strings* :

(each date can be in different order inside ) e.g. :

```
01 feb 2010
feb 01 2010
2010 01 feb
...
...
```

I want to convert a string date to `DateTime`(c#). ( i want the ability to convert every format from above list)

while parse exact requires me `3!` combinations , is there any better solution  ?

Comment: 3! is only 6... However, you could just split on space, and figure out whether each chunk is alphas, 4 digits, or 2 digits... Btw - how does this relate to SQL?

Comment: yeah i know , thats what ive strted to do... but again before i continue , just checking if other solution

Comment: 4 digits for year, 3 chars for months, 2 digits for day. You could use a regex with matching groups and do a single parse exact.

Comment: Sure you wont get "Feb" as 02? THEN you are dead.

Comment: @MarcGravell sql will _always_ know how to parse this format.  nomatter the location of each argument. the datepicker stores the valu in the textbox as this format , and later in c#  - i need to translate it to c# datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i got it ...
[image]

```
string[] str = new[] { "01 feb 2010","feb 01 2010","2010 01 feb","2010 feb 01","feb 2010 01" };
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");                       
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    DateTime t = DateTime.Parse(str[i], culture);
    t.Dump();
}
```

Comment: No need to set (pollute) the `CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`. `Parse(..., culture)` should be enough.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yep...although when i display it DOES change the order ( my computer is at dd/MM/yyyy ) so it shows me : 01/02/2010 ....but just for display (which is irrelevant)

Comment: @abatishchev its like Console.Writeline in Linqpad. http://www.linqpad.net/ (great tool - youll love it)